# paypal ipn passing parameter

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I wanted to get the userid from paypal after the user have made his payment.

Pay.php

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $merchant_email ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="IPN test">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $ipn_url ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return"     value="<?php echo $return_url ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $cancel_url ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="888">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif"
       border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy Now">
```

So I would enable ipn in my paypal account and point to http://www.domain.com/ipn.php?

In ipn.php code

```
<?php
$userid = $_POST['userid'];


$qry = "INSERT into mypayments(userid) VALUES ('$userid') “;
$result = mysql_query($qry,$db);
?>
```

Is it correct? How do I get VERIFIED from paypal?

Answer (score 8):

I believe that **userid** is an incorrect name and will not be returned in your IPN message. I use the optional fields for passing IDs and stuff needed for processing the transaction on my end.

These optional tags are **on0**, **on1**, or **on3** for the custom field names and **os0**, **ls1**, and **os2** for the custom field values. These values can go up to **on6** and **os6**.

I would send **on0** with a value of "UserID" and **os0** the actual ID.

These values will be represented in the IPN as follows:

**os0** is represented as **option_selection1**

**os1** is represented as **option_selection2**

**os2** is represented as **option_selection3**

**on0** is represented as **option_name1**

**on1** is represented as **option_name2**

**on2** is represented as **option_name3**

[Here's the info on PayPal's HTML parameters](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: The custom or invoice parameters can be useful with this sort of thing as well.  As he mentioned, though, userid is not a valid parameter to use with PayPal so they're ignoring it and IPN won't return it.

Comment: How many optional parameters can be passed? Is it three only or does it just keep going?

Comment: I fixed the link in my answer. @user1066133: from PayPal: "You can specify a maximum of 7 option field names (6 with Subscribe buttons) by incrementing the option name index (on0 through on6)."

Comment: Awesome, this solves my issue perfectly. This seems much more efficient than creating something like comma separated values to store in the custom field.

Comment: Do those option_selection1, option_name1, etc, keep being supplied with EVERY IPN message for a transaction? The IPN simulator doesn't allow testing with those.

Comment: Actually, in the PP sandbox, I just went through 3 transactions, including one refund, one with a faulty goods dispute then refund, and one with unauth transaction then refund. The _option_selectionx_ and _option_namex_ variables were included in the IPN message for the major phases of the transaction, like _Completed_, _Reversed_ and _Refunded_, but _custom_ and _invoice_ were included for every IPN message, even for disputes. That means that while the _txn_id_ may not be the same for each related IPN, you can use your defined _custom_ and _invoice_ for your reference continuity.

Comment: Note that it appears that _invoice_ must be unique, if it is provided, as far as PP is concerned, but _custom_ appears freeform. Also note that _custom_ shows up in each IPN message, even if blank, whereas _invoice_ only if not blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "custom" variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="user_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a two step process.

PayPal will post an IPN to the url you specified in `$ipn_url`.

You will then get a `VERIFIED` response when you post all of the IPN data with an additional `cmd=_notify-validate` param ([details](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation)) back to PayPal.

[PHP sample here](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples).

Comment: The PHP code that PP themselves refer to is at https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401#file-completelistener-php, and except for changing the PP target URL for sandbox or live, and inserting the code for what you want it to actually do with the variables PP posts back, it all works as is!